# Force L.control.layers to stay permanently collapsed

Tags: leaflet, css

I am building a map with Leaflet 1.3.1 containing two layers controls (Control1 and Control2). For some reasons, I want one of them (Control2) to be displayed on the map, and I need it to stay **permanently** collapsed (in fact I only want the control background picture to be displayed) :

```
var Control1 = L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps, {collapsed: false}).addTo(map);
var Control2 = L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps, {collapsed: true}).addTo(map);
```

I tried to disable mouse hover events in my CSS :

```
.leaflet-control-layers{
pointer-events: none;}
```

Which does **exactly what I want**, but for both controls.

I only need to apply that style to my Control2 variable, how can I proceed ?

I don't know how to edit L.control.layers class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some modification which will help you to get wanted result :

```js
var Control1 = L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps, {collapsed: false}).addTo(map);
var Control2 = L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps, {collapsed: true}).addTo(map);
Control2.getContainer().className += ' leaflet-control-layers-disable';
```

And for the css part change it to :

```css
.leaflet-control-layers-disable {pointer-events: none;}
```

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly ! Thanks a lot